# rubyOnRails not getting users in my query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want find  that users, whose birthday will come after three days from today.

Because I want to show this users to admin.

So here I am using mongoDb database, and I’ve tried something like this:

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |user|
  p = Profile.in(":dateOfBirth.Date.today.month" => user.profile.dateOfBirth.Date.today.month, ":dateOfBirth.Date.today.day" => user.profile.dateOfBirth.Date.today.day- 3)
  p p.size
end
```

I have this relationship in my user model:

```
class User
  embeds_one :profile
end
```

And this is in my profile model:

```
class Profile
  embedded_in :user
end
```

What I am wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user.profile.dateOfBirth.Date.today.day + 3` if you want the users whose birthday is after 3 days from today?

Comment: yes. 
E.g if XYZ user has birthday on 30/07/2013, then I have to get his birthday reminder on 27/07/2013.

Comment: Are you using mongoid? If so, according to this documentation http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html, you shouldn't be using `Profile.in`. You should be using `Profile.where`